# Потеря\задержка данных при обмене с потоками - как решить? Delphi

Tags: массивы, delphi, многопоточность, события

Или о чем забывают написать в мануалах.
Продолжение вопроса Как правильно передать динамич. массив в поток и обновить его при изменении

Задача вроде банальная - проверить последовательность на уникальность в базе. если уникальна - добавить.
всем управляет форма. потоки чтото делают только после пинка из формы.

Алгоритм формы

Запускам потоки - ждем завершения - забираем результаты - принимаем решение -
запускаем потоки с новыми данными

Алгоритм потока

Посчитали - сообщили о завершении - ждем пинка не передачу результатов - передали - ждем пинка на новый запуск.

Идет борьба за скорость. обьем данных под 1Тб. так-что пара милисек спокойно выростает в часы.

Собственно код. типично Мелкософтовский. вроде правильно работает - пока чтото .......

Проблемма в том что все прекрасно работает пока передача данных из потоков разнесена во времени. даже пинка на запрос данных не нужно.
как только передача из потоков, по времени между событиями, происходит меньше какогото минимума - все. данные теряются.
Не помогает ничего - не критич секции, не post/sendMessage, не Synchronize; причем если в TForm1.THRMSG не коментровать Memo1.Lines.Add или запустит в режиме пошагового дебага - все работает правильно. использование WaitForMultipleObjects в форме дает тотже результат.

По ходу кроме как повесить семафор на TrWorkResArr: TArray; и проверять его на доступность из потока перед передачей невижу.
Если кто подскажет(и покажет) как прикрутить семафор на TrWorkResArr: TArray; и его проверку в потоке. Буду благодарен - вымотала борьба с ветряными мельницами. Написалбы этот кусок на Fortran-е. но весь смысл теряется в потере времени на вызовах.

Вобщем классический постулат программирования - Программа работает как написана, а не так как думает программист.

```
Форма усеченный код uses unit сами добавите - что пропустил, надеюсь лишнее все убрал.
 
const
  ThrCnt = 1; // кол-во потоков
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)

 .......

  private
   TrWorkArr: TArray<TFindTr>;
   MainFEventHandles: THandle; 
    { Private declarations }
  public
    EvHandles: TArray<Tarray<THandle>>;
    TrWorkResArr: TArray<uint32>;
    Flist: TThreadList<uint32>;
    SyncOk: uint32;
    procedure THRMSG(var MSG: TMessage); message THR_MSG;

procedure TForm1.THRMSG(var MSG: TMessage); // прием MSG
begin
   TrWorkResArr[MSG.WParam] := MSG.LParam; // прием результата из потока
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Np  ' + MSG.WParam.ToString +' Stat  '+ MSG.LParam.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);  // create & start 
var
  i: Integer;
  EvtCnt: integer;
begin
  MainFEventHandles := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
  setlength(EvHandles, ThrCnt);
  setlength(TrWorkArr, ThrCnt);
  for i := 0 to ThrCnt-1 do
  begin
    setlength(EvHandles[i], 2);
    EvHandles[i, 0] := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
    EvHandles[i, 1] := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);

    TrWorkArr[i] := TFindTr.Create(false);
    TrWorkArr[i].FreeOnTerminate := true;
    TrWorkArr[i].MainHandle := MainFEventHandles;
    TrWorkArr[i].FWinHandle := Handle;
    TrWorkArr[i].FResumeHandle := EvHandles[i, 1];
    TrWorkArr[i].FStopHandle := EvHandles[i, 0];
    TrWorkArr[i].FIdx := i;
    TrWorkArr[i].FList := Flist;
  end;
  memo1.Lines.Add('start wait events');
  repeat
   if CheckBox1.Checked = false then EvtCnt := ThrCnt; // отпускаем потоки в сомомстоятельное плаванье
   if CheckBox1.Checked = true then begin // контролируем работу потоков
    MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, MainFEventHandles, false, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT); // ждем что ктото что-то сделал 
    EvtCnt := 0;
    for i := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do begin  // подсчет всех флагов
     EvtCnt := EvtCnt + TrWorkArr[i].EventStatus;
     memo1.Lines.Add('End event  ' + EvtCnt.ToString +' Tr Id '+ TrWorkArr[i].FIdx.ToString +'  Tr Stst  ' +TrWorkArr[i].EventStatus.ToString);
    end;
    memo1.Lines.Add('');
   end;
  until EvtCnt = ThrCnt; // если кол-во флагов равно выполнененым флагам алгоритма в потоке * на кол потоков

 for i := 0 to WorkThCnt - 1 do begin     // чтение результатов
   SetEvent(EvHandles[i, 1]);   // запрос на передачу
   MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, MainFEventHandles, false, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT); 
   FindResult := FindResult + TrWorkResArr[i];
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);  // запуск без TFindTr.Create 
var
 i: uint32;
begin
 for I := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do begin
  SetEvent(EvHandles[i, 1]);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject); // break цикла вычелений
var
 i: uint32;
begin
 for I := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do begin
  PostThreadMessage(TrWorkArr[i].ThreadID, WM_USER, 0, 0);
 end;
end;


// POTOK UNIT

unit FindTr;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections, Math;

const
  THR_MSG = WM_USER + 666;

type
  TFindTr = class(TThread)
  private
    FEventHandles: array [0 .. 1] of THandle;   // 0: immediate stop; 1: resume treatment
    { Private declarations }
  public
  FIdx: integer;
  EventStatus: uint32; //  флаг что был Event
  FWinHandle, FResumeHandle, FStopHandle: THandle;
  MainHandle: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TFindTr }

procedure TFindTr.OutRes;
begin
 Form1.TrWorkResArr[FIdx] := FindResult;
end;

procedure TFindTr.Execute;
var
  List: TList<TData>;
  WaitRes: Integer;
  Data: TData;
  i, sm, n: Integer;
  msg: TMsg;

begin
 FEventHandles[0] := FStopHandle;
 FEventHandles[1] := FResumeHandle;
 sm := 0;
 repeat
 for n := 1 to 10 do begin
  EventStatus := 0;
  EventStatus := 1;
  SetEvent(MainHandle);
  sleep(RandomRange(1000,2500));   // типа работаем
  if PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then begin // тут проверяем если нужно оборвать расчеты
   case msg.message of
    WM_USER: break;
   end;
   end;
  end;

{  List := Flist.LockList; // не работает
   try
   List.Add(FindResult);
   finally
   Flist.UnlockList;
      end;}
//    Form1.TrWorkResArr[FIdx] := FindResult; // не работает

    sendMessage(FWinHandle, WM_USER, 0, 0); // MSG End work
    WaitRes := WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @FEventHandles, false, INFINITE); // in read result
    ResetEvent(FEventHandles[0]);
    ResetEvent(FEventHandles[1]);
//    Synchronize(OutRes); // не работает

    sendMessage(FWinHandle, THR_MSG, FIdx, FindResult); // MSG read result не работает
    WaitRes := WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @FEventHandles, false, INFINITE); // wait restart 
    ResetEvent(FEventHandles[0]);
    ResetEvent(FEventHandles[1]);
    inc(sm, 1);
  until WaitRes = WAIT_OBJECT_0; // ImmediateStop
end;

end.
```

Comment: В вопросе какой-то поток сознания. Если хотите решить проблему, напишите минимально-воспроизводимый код, где она проявляется. Без форм и прочей обвязки, а просто консольное приложение с одним дополнительным потоком. И возможно, что в процессе подготовки этого примера вы и самостоятельно разберётесь в прблеме.

Comment: По моей ссылке из прошлого поста есть код BlockToAsyncBuf, может быть, он вам подойдёт. А насчёт `List := Flist.LockList; // не работает`  - вы могли видеть, что в моём примере работает. Но это решение для нечастых событий.

Comment: это вопрос или ответ?

Comment: Еще насчёт алгоритма поиска-обновления вопросы есть, хотя это уже другая тема. Обработка терабайта при чтении с обычного жесткого диска должна занимать быть обусловлена временем чтения, т.е. минут 20. Применяются ли правильные структуры данных (например, хэш-таблица для точного поиска)?

Comment: MBo естественно предобработка есть. сначала вычисляется полином последовательности. на основе полинома обьеденяем  в блоки. а после на основе MD5 дубляж в блоке и базе. а уже потом что осталось в блоке проверяется на уникальность. но там уже все вылизано как у кота....

Answer (score 0):

Собственно решение найдено, но не все решено.
Огромное спасибо Всем за корректный пинок, на тему - кашу в голове нужно перемешивать, иначе - пригорает.

Вообщем траблы решены и вполне корректно - без костылей типа Sleep. Правда 1 вопрос остался.
Итак то о чем забывают написать в мануалах. Опять-же - это мое понимание.

MsgWaitForMultipleObjects - во время ожидания обработка списка MSG не ведется. Если ожидается больше 1 MSG, в обработку передается только одно. какое из них ????? и обязатально  application.ProcessMessages; после выхода. иначе обработка списка не начнется.

```
EventStatus := 1;
WaitForMultipleObjects
```

- если присвоение и постановка в ожидание происходит меньше какого-то крит. минимума внутри SystemTick - значение не доежает до интерфейсной секции потока. Решения не нашел. костыль типа sleep ломается.

Код рабочий. Потоки контролируемые. ожидание не морозит форму. Лишнего процессорного времени не требует. Кому надо можно поставить потоки - каждому потоку по  своему ядру. Проверен на 10 потоках в течении 12 часов. Ошибок не было. Наверно мало гонял. )))
По факту - написать оказалось проще и быстрее. даже с учетом граблей. больше времени ушло на понимание что-же авторы мануалов пытались сказать. Особенно в своих примерах. Осталось прикрутить Break потоков на выполнение дурной работы. Будут вопросы по коду - задавайте. Смогу отвечу.

Собственно код - на форме 1 кнопка и мемо. названия стандартные. FunTime - LIB для замера времени. можно выкинуть.

форма

```
const
  THR_MSG = WM_USER + 666;
  stop_MSG = WM_USER + 100;

  private
   TrWorkArr: TArray<THFind>;
   MainFEventHandles: THandle;
    { Private declarations }
  public
   EvHandles: TArray<Tarray<THandle>>;
   TrWorkResArr: TArray<uint32>;
   SyncOK: uint32;
   EndFlg: uint32;
   ThrCnt: byte;
   MList: TStringlist;
   procedure THRMSG(var MSG: TMessage); message THR_MSG;
   procedure THRMSGstop(var MSG: TMessage); message stop_MSG;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.THRMSG(var MSG: TMessage);
begin
  TrWorkResArr[MSG.WParam] := MSG.LParam;
   MList.Add('Np  ' + MSG.WParam.ToString +' FinRes  '+ MSG.LParam.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.THRMSGstop(var MSG: TMessage);
begin
   MList.Add('Np stop ' + MSG.WParam.ToString +' Sleep  '+ MSG.LParam.ToString);
   inc(EndFlg, 1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i, n: uint32;
 WaitHandle: TArray<THandle>;
 waitres: integer;
 WT: RecTime;
begin
 ThrCnt := 4;
 memo1.Clear;
 MList := TStringlist.Create;
 MainFEventHandles := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
  setlength(EvHandles, ThrCnt);
  setlength(TrWorkArr, ThrCnt);
  setlength(TrWorkResArr, ThrCnt);
  setlength(WaitHandle, ThrCnt);
 for I := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do begin
  TrWorkResArr[i] := 0;
  setlength(EvHandles[i], 2);
  EvHandles[i, 0] := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
  EvHandles[i, 1] := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);

  TrWorkArr[i] := THFind.Create(true);
  TrWorkArr[i].FreeOnTerminate := true;
  TrWorkArr[i].Priority := tpNormal;
  TrWorkArr[i].MainHandle := MainFEventHandles;
  TrWorkArr[i].FWinHandle := Form1.Handle;
  TrWorkArr[i].FResumeHandle := EvHandles[i, 1];
  TrWorkArr[i].FStopHandle := EvHandles[i, 0];
  TrWorkArr[i].FIdx := i;
  WaitHandle[i] := TrWorkArr[i].Handle;
 end;
 starttime(wt);
 for n := 0 to 10 do begin
  for I := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do begin
   if TrWorkArr[i].Suspended = true then TrWorkArr[i].Resume
    else
      SetEvent(EvHandles[i, 1]);
  end;
 try
  EndFlg := 0;
  SyncOk := 0;
  while EndFlg <> ThrCnt do begin
   MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, TrWorkArr, false, INFINITE,  QS_SENDMESSAGE);
   application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
  MList.Add('');
  except
//   ShowMessage('n ' + n.ToString);
  end;
 end;
 stoptime(wt);
 memo1.Lines := MList;
 memo1.Lines.Add('OK');
 Memo1.Lines.Add(DecodeRecTime(wt));
  for I := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do begin
    SetEvent(EvHandles[i, 0]);
  end;
 MList.Free;
end;
end.
```

Поток

```
unit TTHFind;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections, math;

const
  THR_MSG = WM_USER + 666;
  stop_MSG = WM_USER + 100;


type
  ThFind = class(TThread)
  private
   FEventHandles: array [0 .. 1] of THandle;   // 0: immediate stop; 1: resume treatment
    { Private declarations }
  public
   FIdx: integer;
   EventStatus: uint32;
   FWinHandle, FResumeHandle, FStopHandle: THandle;
   MainHandle: THandle;
   FindResult: byte;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

{ ThFind }

procedure ThFind.Execute;
var
   WaitRes, n,sm: Integer;
begin
   FEventHandles[0] := FStopHandle;
   FEventHandles[1] := FResumeHandle;
   sm := 0;
  repeat
   EventStatus := 0;
   FindResult := 0;
  if FIdx = 0 then sm := RandomRange(100, 200);
  if FIdx = 1 then sm := RandomRange(1000, 2000);
  if FIdx > 1 then sm := RandomRange(10, 100);
    sleep(sm);
   FindResult := 1;
   SendMessage(FWinHandle, stop_MSG, FIdx, sm);
   sendMessage(FWinHandle, THR_MSG, FIdx, FindResult);
   EventStatus := 1;
   WaitRes := WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @FEventHandles, false, INFINITE); // in end work
   ResetEvent(FEventHandles[0]);
   ResetEvent(FEventHandles[1]);
    inc(sm, 1);
  until WaitRes = WAIT_OBJECT_0; // ImmediateStop
 free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Работает стабильно, Считает правильно. Особого прироста по скорости пока не заметил, но в отличие от TTask результат по времени стабильный и не зависит от чиха системы. все таки i5 2+2 это 2 + 0.75 Xeon-a. Остается прикручивать индексацию базы. из производительности уже все выжато. Один вопрос можно-ли  очистить список message потоку не через while PeekMessage а одной командой ???